# Application pool SharePoint 80 get stopped.. dont now why

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

i tryed to use ITextSharper yesterday today i started my server got HTTP ERROR 503 , after trying to deploy i find out that my application pool get stopped when i try to go to my site in internet explorer , i have tried to reset the application pool but still got same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the password has not changed or expired for the Application Pool service account.

Answer (score 1):

If password of Application Pool account is not expired, check this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22885/application-pool-is-auto-stopped-when-browse-web-application-in-iis7).